# NoClassDefFoundError when downgrade Androod support lib from 23.2.0 to 23.1.1

Tags: android, android-library

I've update the Android Support Library from version 23.1.1 to 23.2.0 and have to update the Android Support Library Repository in Android studio. Since there's some bugs in the new version, I want to downgrade it.
After downgrading to 23.1.1, I got these errors

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: android/support/v7/widget/TintManager;
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1185)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:656)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:695)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:386)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:361)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:645)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:616)
at co.appedu.snapask.activity.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:174)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2321)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

when I call
    `TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager)`

The same code can compile before upgrade the Support Library

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: let clean your project -> rebuild. still get error let check and look some error warning by editor with red line -> replace it with valid class

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you also updated other dependencies. I had similar issue and my problem was in other library which depended on 23.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @basv said, 23.1.1 contains TineManager class, 23.2.0 removed it.
Material Design Lib of 23.1.1 depends on TineManager. So upgrade two libs at the same time.

I tried this way successfully. I hope you so, haha.